# I have checkedin with 5 workitems in tfs,now how to delete these workitems from the check in to have only one workitem in tfs

Tags: tfs

I have checked in with 5 workitems in tfs.

Now how to delete these workitems from the check in to have only one workitem in tfs?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you check in some items with 5 related work items, but now you just want to relate one work item with the items.

You can simply delete the changset link in the work items you don't want to relate:

[image]

Comment: but from checkin which i have already checkedin, i want to delete these workitems.

Comment: @varun, After you delete the changeset link in the work items, they will disappear from the check-in. You can try it.

Comment: i have a codereviewed for 1 workitem and code is for some other workitem.How to change this code review workitem in code review request or during checkin?? thanks in advance.

Comment: @varun, You would need to use witadmin destroywi command to remove work items permanently: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd236908(v=vs.120).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can't delete a work item in TFS 2013. Depending on your work item's workflow, you can set the state of the work item to something like closed or complete.

The deletion of work items feature was [only introduced in TFS 2015.2](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/backlogs/remove-delete-work-items).